# The best way to connect application to MySQL database

Tags: python, mysql, connection, vpn

I have a general question of what is the best way to connect a production app to a database server. So, I am planning to make an application which will need to have a direct connection to MySQL database. Database itself will be hosted in the same building on dedicated server with no access from outside world (Network). My question is. Will I use some type of REST service or I can make a direct connection from my application to the database server using SSL encryption? The other question is, there is a possibility that we say 2 more sites will need to have a direct connection to that database is well. In this case can I use VPN connection with SSL without REST service and make all the requests in my code in functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [**sqlalchemy**](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) to connect directly to the data base and use its [**ORM**](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/engines.html#mysql), so you'll do everything programmatically.

But i would say that good practise is to create a [**RESTfull API**](https://rocketeer.be/blog/2015/03/api-quality/) and make calls to your db through that API. There is a good library [**Sandman**](https://github.com/jeffknupp/sandman) which might help you.

Comment: So it looks like I will have to spent some time and try to make my own API for the DB, thanks for your answer.

Comment: the link i gave for the sandman is because it'll create a simple rest wrapper around your db and you can dance from that

Comment: That will help me a lot but there is a long way of learning about REST service ;)

Comment: well to be honest rest is very simple, all you do is that you are handling requests like GET and POST and send back responses. In flask simple API might be written in several strings, and in django too actually.

Comment: I have seen FLASK and Django REST services and they don't look complicated I need to get some book any way about good practices and design choices

Comment: no need books, read this one http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/designing-a-restful-api-with-python-and-flask

Comment: if my answer helped you you can accept my answer by clicking v